# Update list of data in a custom way

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a scenario and want to know the best possible way to handle it.

I have a user who has n number of addresses.

addressList (id) for example (which I get at frontend) -

```
addresses=[1,2,3,4]
```

Once I fetch all the addresses to the frontend, the user can delete one or n number of addresses.

> Note - The delete is only removing the address object from the list
> (at frontend) and not permanently delete it from the database.

so here, addressList now can be -

```
addresses=[1,4]
```

Also, the users add n number of new addresses

the new addressList may be -

```
addresses=[1,4, {newAddressDetail}, {newAddressDetail}]
```

Now this updated data (addresses) is sent over to the backend for the update process.

Would like to know how to handle this scenario best at the backend?

Things are -

- delete all the previously saved addresses which are not received currently.
- Not to alter the previously saved addresses which are received currently.
- create new addresses which are not in the database.

It is not advised to delete an address from the database when the user removes it from the frontend. The address is not editable at the frontend and the data which I have shown here is only for the explanation purpose and are not correct technically.

Can provide more details if required.

Comment: I know the longer way to filter each previous data with the current received data, looking for a smarter way  :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to use `sets` in python.

So in your backend something like:

```py
new = set(addresses_from_frontend)
old = set(user.addresses.all())

Address.objects.bulk_create([Address(**item) for item in old - new])
Address.objects.filter(id__in=[a.id for a in new - old]).delete()
```

Its not gonna look exactly like this, you are probably gonna have to use the address ids to get the addresses before  deleting them and so forth. But the main point is that sets are an efficient way of doing this [bulk_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) and [delete()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#delete) using a filter can also help you get your db queries down.

Comment: The same thing I'm trying manually, storing the ids to be deleted in a local list, stroing the ids not to be touched in another local list, as I mentioned in my comment. Will look at how sets work though.

Comment: ok, ive edited my answer a little. using [values_list('id', flat=True)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list) might also help

Comment: Yes, already using values_list. To be true have never used sets. This seems the good time. Let me learn this and apply. Will write how it goes.

Comment: So key points relevant to this question are:

membership (find something inside)
set: O(1), list: O(n)

finding the different items between two sets/lists:
set: O(1), list: O(n).

Comment: By default, the parent serializer does not get the id of the child serializer in the update method if we check the validated_data of the serializer (other fields are there), I found putting **id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)** in child serializer works, any idea if this is safe?